# #@save definition and importance python

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, google-colaboratory

I have seen this `#@save` in multiple instances in python most often in Jupyter and Colab notebooks. Please explain the usage of this operator, the importance, and how to use it. An example is shown below.

```
#@save
import collections
from collections import defaultdict
from IPython import display
```

Comment: # is comment, so python jignores it.  But co,ab may use it.  `#!python`, 'shebang' is used by linux shells.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are following d2l pytorch book like me then the explanation is given at page 68 Chapter 2. "Note that the comment #@save is a special mark
where the following function, class, or statements are saved in the d2l package so later they can
be directly invoked (e.g., d2l.use_svg_display()) without being redefined."

Relevant link: [https://d2l.ai/chapter_preliminaries/calculus.html#:~:text=To%20visualize%20such,without%20being%20redefined](https://d2l.ai/chapter_preliminaries/calculus.html#:%7E:text=To%20visualize%20such,without%20being%20redefined).

Comment: This does not answer OPs question properly. Please consider providing links to the sources mentioned otherwise put this in comments

Answer (score 1):

If there is a  `#@save` before a function, it means this has been stored in the d2l.

for example, you don't need to define a function(which existed on the book) again if you import the d2l:

```
from d2l import torch as d2l
d2l.use_svg_display()
```

See it? there is no error, but remember use the "d2l." before use the function.